# Como pegar o valor do select

Tags: react

Como faço para pegar o valor do `select`, dei um `onChange`, mas o valor não está sendo retornado como esperado.

```
<select
  className="form-control"
  value={area}
  onChange={e => setAddArea(e.target.value)}
>
  <option disabled selected>
    Selecione
  </option>
  {getArea.map((ar, i) => (
    <option key={i} value={ar.area}>
      {ar.area}
    </option>
  ))}
</select>;

async function handleCreate(e, area) {
  e.preventDefault();

  const response = await api.post("/pergunta", {
    area,
    pergunta
  });
  console.log(response.data);
}

const [area, setAddArea] = useState("");
```

Comment: Como você sabe que não está retornando o valor esperado? Esse código parece meio incompleto...

Comment: estou usando react hooks, usei o useState

Comment: Aonde está a sua chamada para o handleCreate?

Comment: Coloquei no button para quando der o click ele enviar os dados que serão recebidos pela api <button type="submit" className="btn btn-outline-success" onClick={handleCreate}>Adicionar</button>

Comment: O problema está, exatamente, na forma que você está usando o `handleCreate`, já que ele está recebendo como parâmetro área, ele está escrevendo como `undefined` essa área, não?

Comment: Se o `e.target.value` não é undefined, então o problema é no seu método `setAddArea`.

Comment: @FelipeAvelar o que eu não entendo é que com o input  <input
                className="form-control" 
                value={pergunta}
                onChange={e => setAddPergunta(e.target.value)}
                placeholder="Digite a Pergunta"
                /> pode ser feito da mesma forma ele enviar o valor correto, só o select que não funciona

Comment: @PedroHenrique edita tua pergunta, colocando como tá esse teu componente. Imagino que o problema seja no `handleCreate` e não pegando o valor do select...

Comment: @FelipeAvelar Mas o handleCreate só é uma função que vou chamar ela quando o usuário de o click no botão.

Comment: @PedroHenrique você viu o exemplo online que eu coloquei [Exemplo Online](https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-sanderson-z6y0h?fontsize=14) ? e inclusive tem na resposta ?

Comment: @PedroHenrique o exemplo local também está rodando! dê uma olhada

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema não está em coletar o valor do `select`, mas no fato de você estar [criando um novo escopo](https://medium.com/weyes/entendendo-o-uso-de-escopo-no-javascript-3669172ca5ba) para a variável `area`, como aponto o @VirgilioNovic. Segue um exemplo de componente aplicável que resolve o seu problema:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function Example() {
  const [selectValue, setSelectValue] = useState(1);  
  const list = [
    {id: 1, name: 'select 1'},
    {id: 2, name: 'select 2'},
    {id: 3, name: 'select 3'},
    {id: 4, name: 'select 4'},
  ];

  function handleCreate(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    alert(selectValue)  
  }

  return (    
    <div>
      <p>{selectValue}</p>
      <select value={selectValue} onChange={e => setSelectValue(e.target.value)}>
        {list.map((item, index) => (
          <option value={item.id}>{item.name}</option>
        ))}        
      </select>
      <button onClick={handleCreate}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Example;
```

Perceba que no `handleCreate` foi removido a variável `area` dos parâmetros que ele recebe, justamente pra não criar uma variável local para a função e aproveitar a area que está associada ao `state` do componente.

Comment: Muito Obrigado, deu certo.

Answer (score 2):

*Pelo visto estava quase conseguindo resolver*, quando você cria um variável `area` e o seu método de alteração `setAddArea` ([React Hooks](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)) você já fez aonde vai ficar o valor da seleção, e conforme muda o `select` no evento `onChange` faz a alteração (`e.target.value`) e após essa modificação na variável `area` tem o valor do `select` como precisa. Se no código precisar utilizar o valor da seleção é só atribuir o valor da variável `area`.

[Um exemplo rodando em Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-sanderson-z6y0h?fontsize=14)

```js
function App () {
  const [selectValue, setSelectValue] = React.useState(1);  
  const list = [
    {id: 1, name: 'select 1'},
    {id: 2, name: 'select 2'},
    {id: 3, name: 'select 3'},
    {id: 4, name: 'select 4'},
  ];
  return (    
    <div>
      <p>{selectValue}</p>
      <select value={selectValue} onChange={e => setSelectValue(e.target.value)}>
        {list.map((item, index) => (
          <option value={item.id}>{item.name}</option>
        ))}        
      </select>
    </div>
  )
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Tem um método no seu código `async function handleCreate(e, area)` que você tem o `area` como parâmetro, mas, é desnecessário é só utilizar, ***exemplo***:

```js
async function handleCreate(e) {
  e.preventDefault()        
  const response = await api.post('/pergunta', {
      area,//<-- isso já é o suficiente
      pergunta
  }) 
}
```

Comment: Porque recebi voto negativo? pode explicar

Comment: Até onde eu entendi, é exatamente isso que ele está fazendo e não resolve o problema dele...

Comment: @FelipeAvelar como você sabe que não é isso?

Comment: Porque o seu exemplo está praticamente igual ao da pergunta, só que ele está usando um handle, o que não é contemplado no seu exemplo...

Comment: Osh, não dei o voto negativo, vou tentar executar, mas pelo visto, é a mesma forma que fiz, só retorna undefined, mas obrigado.

Comment: @FelipeAvelar mais olha a pergunta dele e o que ele está perguntando, eu não mereço levar voto negativo!

Comment: @VirgilioNovic, eu entendo que você recebeu como pega o valor no `onChange`, mas a dúvida é relativo ao fato de ele não ter o valor esperado no `handleCreate`, não de não estar pegando o valor no `select`, até porque ele pega da mesma forma que você colocou no exemplo...

Comment: @FelipeAvelar mas, eu mereço voto negativo mediante a pergunta: **Como pegar o valor do select React** e olha como eu expliquei!

Comment: @VirgilioNovic, eu vou remover o negativo, mas você concorda que isso não resolve o problema dele?

Comment: @FelipeAvelar resolve sim, o problema dele é o que está na pergunta não o que imaginamos, você precisa entender que respondemos de acordo com a pergunta não imaginação, eu expliquei como resgata o valor do Select!

Comment: @VirgilioNovic, agora sim, com essa edição resolve o problema. (:

Comment: @VirgilioNovic muito Obrigado