# Como pegar o "value" de um select no ReactJS

Tags: javascript, react, select, javascript-eventos, onclick

Fiz o seguinte código, gostaria de pegar o valor do "value" do select, (a cor do carro e mostrar na tag h3 quando o botão é acionado) tentei usar .target.value porém sem sucesso

[Código no codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-heyrovsky-ev0yt?file=/src/Resultado.js:0-651)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function Resultado() {
  const [valor, setValor] = useState("Cor");

  return (
    <section>
      <div>
        <h3>Cor do Carro</h3>
        <select>
          <option value="Vermelho" selected>
            Uno
          </option>
          <option value="Branca">Parati</option>
          <option value="Azul">Fusca</option>
        </select>
        <button
          onClick={(event) => {
            setValor(event.target.value);
          }}
        >
          Enviar Resultado
        </button>
      </div>

      <h3>A cor do carro é: {valor}</h3>
    </section>
  );
}
```

Comment: [Esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/404856/como-pegar-o-valor-do-select?rq=1) irá lhe ajudar. Basicamente o que deve ser feito é mover esse `(event) => {setValor(event.target.value); }` para o `select` no evento `onChange`. Ficaria +- assim: `<select onChange={(event) => {setValor(event.target.value);}>`

Answer (score 0):

Olá, você pode chegar ao resultado desejado modificando o seu codigo para o seguinte:

```
<select onChange={(e) => setValor(e.target.value)}>
          <option value="Vermelho" selected>
            Uno
          </option>
          <option value="Branca">Parati</option>
          <option value="Azul">Fusca</option>
        </select>
```

Cada vez que um item diferente for selecionado ele irá atualizar o valor do hook.